# two identical arduino Nano`s running at different speeds?

Tags: arduino

I am working on a project that requires me to use 2 separate Arduinos running independently from each other. Now, both of these Arduino's are running the same code, but I noticed that after 10 minutes or so, one of them falls behind and this time difference keep increasing with time. Like I already mentioned, the Arduino`s are identical and I bought them at the same time and they are running the same copy of the program. Any ideas what might cause this and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Here is the link to the Arduino that I bought just in case.
[My Arduino modules on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UACD13Q)

Answer (score 1):

The Crystal Oszillators have tolerances up to 100ppm (extreme case), which means you could possibly get 16Mhz*100ppm = 1600 clock pulses difference per second. Also the differences of the runtime could be caused by small voltage differences. Even if there is a voltage Regulator on the Board it has small tolerances, based on the fact, that it operates in the Range of MHz this can climb up to an recognizable Offset.

A possible solution is a synchronization of both microcontrollers. I'm not an expert, so the following solution is a possible and easy one, but definitly not the best.
If they are near by each other you can use two pins of each controller. One as Input and one as Output. Write something like this in your code (same for both if you use the same Pins):

```
digitalWrite(outPin, LOW);
while(digitalRead(inPin)){};
digitalWrite(outPin, HIGH);
```

Connect the Output from the first to the Input from the second and the same from second to first.
This results in a waiting state for each cycle of the faster Controller until the slower one reaches the same Programm Part. **But be careful** if one of them stucks somewhere it will stop the second one too. So there is **no redundancy**! if this was your goal, don't use this method and search for other synchronisation methods.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The nature of the project requires 2 Arduino's to be about 20m apart from each other so I can't keep them connected at all times unfortunately. Do you think it is a good idea to add voltage regulators to Arduino`s ? Would this have any chance of solving my problem ?

Comment: The Arduino already have Voltage regulators. That will not solve the Problem. Perhaps you can add some wireless connection to fullfill the principle (bluetooth may be to low range on 20m, but there are some Modules on the market). Otherwise i would suggest to google something like "Microcontroller synchronisation" or similiar. I think the chances are high, that someone conquered the same Problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use some RTC (real time clock) hardware to help you to keep they synchronised. They are really cheap and easy to use.